# Como cifrar un password actualizado

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-6

Estoy trabajando con shinobi y laravelCollective en laravel 6. Pasa que estoy haciendo la funcion **update** en el **CRUD** algo asi:

```
public function update(Request $request, User $user)
{
    $user->update($request->all());

    return redirect()->route('users.index')
            ->with('info', 'Usuario actualizado con exito');
}
```

Esto me actualiza correctamente al usuario, sin embargo pierdo la capacidad de iniciar sesion, pues tambien se actualiza el password pero no se cifra, por lo que el auth me manda un mensaje de error de clave erronea. Hay una manera de cifrar la clave usando esa sintaxis para crear la funcion? o unicamente se puede de la siguente manera:

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{

    $users = App\User::findOrFail($id);
    $users->direc = $request->direc;
    $users->tlf = $request->tlf;
    $users->email = $request->email;
    $users->password = Hash::make($request->password);

    $users->save();

    return view('users.index');
}
```

ingresando dato por dato y usando el **`Hash::make`**.

Answer (score 0):

Básicamente tienes que usar el facade Hash para "encriptar" la contraseña, con su método make, de lo contrario deberías, cualquier caracteres que envías, en lo tomara como clave encriptada, y te lo actualizara

Answer (score 0):

Considera manejar esto a través de un **mutator** el cual dará formato a un atributo del modelo que en este caso es `User`.

Dentro de tu modelo `User.php` define el siguiente *setter*

```
class User extends Model
{
    public function setPasswordAttribute($value)
    {
        $this->attributes['password'] = bcrypt($value);
    }
}
```

- En el nombre del método añadimos el nombre de la propiedad que deseamos modificar justo antes de que se mande a la base de datos; en este caso es `password`
- Para hacer el *hash* de la contraseña usamos el *helper* [`bcrypt`](https://laravel.com/docs/master/helpers#method-bcrypt)

**Referencia**

- [*mutators* en Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-mutators#defining-a-mutator)

Comment: Nota: Tienes que tener cuidado con el mutador si tu aplicacion soportara recuperacion de contraseña