# ¿Cómo modificar el valor de un campo para luego guardarlo?

Tags: laravel

Recibo en mi controlador todos los campos de un formulario con:

```
$user = User::create($request->all());
```

ahora necesito, modificar $request->password para encriptarlo antes de guardarlo, pero no sé como hacerlo.

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado?, revisa esto: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/328053/como-cifrar-un-password-actualizado/328059#328059 creo es lo que buscas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes utilizar el [Hash facade](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/hashing) de Laravel.

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;

$user = User::
   create($request->except('password') + ['password' => Hash::make($request->password)]);
```

Comment: Mil gracias! funcionó a la perfección!